# Go to new line on enter keypress in Console

Tags: c#, console-application

How can I go to a new line on a keypress in a console application.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       var button = Console.ReadKey();
        if(button.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter){
            newline;
        }
    }
```

For example: I want to make something that will go to a new line when the user presses the enter key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
     while ( true )
     {
        var button = Console.ReadKey();
        if ( button.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter )
        {
           Console.WriteLine();
        }            
     }
```

Comment: Note that you can also manipulate the cursor location using `Console.WindowTop` or `Console.CursorTop`and the `Left` equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to go to next line, use

```
  Console.Write(System.Environment.NewLine);
```

if you need add empty line, use

```
  Console.WriteLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
Console.WriteLine();
```

This should move to a new line for you.